# Merging branches in tortoiseHg does not seem to work

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, branching-and-merging

In a project, I have a default branch and another named branch. After a merging both branches and committing it, the graph in TortoiseHg shows that both branches have been merged. However, pushing to a remote repository (which is at the stage before branching, it only has the default branch), I get the message "abort: push creates new remote branches".

If I'm not mistaken, I'm left with one branch after merging, so why this error message? Note: the graph still shows that I have 2 heads, is it in anyway related to this?

Comment: Did some other pushed changes into the remote repository? What does `Mark incoming changes` show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting that error message because the named branch -- and all its changesets -- still exists in your local repository: you've merged the changes into the `default` branch, that's all.

You see two heads because you're using a named branch: from the [help text](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#commands) for `hg heads` (the command line equivalent of selecting *Heads* in the repository explorer):

> Branch heads are changesets that have no child changeset on the same branch.

Since you have two branches in your local repository (`default` and the named branch), you have two heads by definition.

To resolve the error message that you're getting, in the repository explorer, there's a *Push New Branch* option at the bottom of the *Synchronize* menu; select it, then you should be able to push to the remote repository.

Comment: OK, I got it, thanks. I thought that merging a named branch into the default branch would remove/destroy the named branch, which is not the case.